# SQLCipher data takes more space in memory?

Tags: memory, size, sqlcipher

I am working with an sqlite database in my android app. I read data from url and write it into database using android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement. This way I get about 1.5 MB app data. Recently, I switched to net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteStatement, now I get about 8.5 MB app data, which is approx. 5 times bigger. Why is it so? is there a way to decrease data size while using sqlcipher still?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional application data size is due to the inclusion of the ICU data file. For more information, see the [Location Dependencies section of the SQLCipher for Android documentation](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/):

> SQLCipher for Android depends on localization data from the ICU
>   project. SQLCipher for Android will attempt to use a system provided
>   ICU localization data file called icudt46l.dat located in the
>   /system/usr/icu directory if available. If that is not found,
>   SQLCipher for Android will attempt to unzip the icudt46l.zip file
>   located within the applications asset directory. It is recommended
>   that the icudt46.zip file be included with your application for best
>   platform compatibility. If you need to adjust the size of the
>   localization data for your application, a ICU data library customizer
>   is available here.